# MacOS build issues lstdc++ not found while building python package

Tags: python, macos, clang, homebrew

While trying to install python dependencies on MacOS I encountered a build error.

```
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I have xcode installed, and the xcode command line tools, and I use homebrew, so I have gcc 9.1 installed via homebrew.

Another concerning thing I see in the build is this:

```
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
```

my concern being that I'm not sure what macosx-10.7 refers to? I'm running mojave (10.14) and xcode is version 10.2.1, so what does 10.7 refer to?

Comment: You probably want to install those Python dependencies with the gcc installed through Homebrew then; that'll have no problem with its own libstdc++. You could try and put the path to gcc at the front of your PATH when building them; or adjust the setup.py.

Comment: I think the 10.7 is just very generic, and indicates anything compatible with 10.7 and upwards. But that's just a guess.

Comment: For what it's worth: I'm seeing a `build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7` on my machine for MacOS 10.14.4. That is a C/Cython extension, no C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, this seems to do the trick (for bash):

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9`

I'm still not sure what 10.7 is vs 10.9, but this line in the error log:

```
move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
```

lead to me discovering that exporting the deployment target effectively did what it was asking for.